# Installation of netbeans 8.1 from the .sh file in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, command-line, bash, netbeans

I have the installation file `netbeans-8.1-linux.sh` in the Others folder of Downloads.

Now when I am using the command from the Netbeans official site to make the installer file executable i.e.

```
chmod +x <netbeans-8.1-linux.sh>
```

It is showing the following error

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
```

So what do I have to do?? Do I have to use the `sudo` command means like this

```
sudo./Downloads/Others/chmod +x <netbeans-8.1-linux.sh>
```

but it's showing the same error.
So if anyone could help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First get the installer

```
wget download.netbeans.org/netbeans/8.1/final/bundles/netbeans-8.1-linux.sh
```

Now give it executable permissions

```
chmod +x netbeans-8.1-linux.sh
```

Now to execute it run from its directory

```
sudo sh netbeans-8.1-linux.sh
```

This will start the installer

As requested in comments, here is a one liner

```
wget download.netbeans.org/netbeans/8.1/final/bundles/netbeans-8.1-linux.sh && chmod +x netbeans-8.1-linux.sh && sudo sh netbeans-8.1-linux.sh
```

Alternatively there is an old version in the repository’s, you can install with one command

```
sudo apt-get install netbeans
```

Comment: It is showing this error.                                                                                          Installer file /home/coder/Downloads/Others/netbeans-8.1-linux.sh seems to be corrupted.
Now what to do?

Comment: Download it again, it works fine for me, something must of gone wrong.

Comment: Ok..isn't there any terminal commands through which I can get the latest netbeans ??If there are then please let me know..@mark

Comment: Please tell me what language you wish to use netbeans for, so I can get you the correct one you want

Comment: But I want to use netbeans for java,html and sometimes c programming too..It will be better if you could tell me to install the entire package directly so that I could use all the languages which are provided by netbeans.

Comment: OK we will the `all` version so you can use it for anything, one moment please.

Comment: Sorry I can make it a bit eaisyer, see the new edit in a minuet, if this works please accept with the check mark on the left

Comment: Ok updated for you

Comment: Ok thanks i heve deleted the old netbeans file and Downloading netbeans the one liner coder..Thanx bdw.:)

Comment: Please let me know if you have any issues with these commands :)

Comment: Yeah of course..one thing I wanna ask..Please don't mind but did you write the one liner code all by yourself or is there any website or manual where I can refer to how to install anything? The latest version of any software of course.@mrk

Comment: I wrote it, it is the three commands at the begging of the question, just connected by `&&`, so it is the same commands, just ran in a row. && tells apt, do this if the last command succeed, there is nothing special about the one liner its self. Try it in your terminal, you can stack any command like this.

Comment: I present it both ways as the one liner is hard to read for others at a glance

Comment: Ok.got it means after running the one liner netbeans will be not only be downloaded but also installed directly.isn't it?.

Comment: Yes it downloads it from the netbeans site, then chmods it and runs the installer, you will need to follow the installer still, there is no way around that because of how they packaged it.